# How to do data design without database?

Tags: design, data-structures, data

I already to do research on internet about data design, they all explain how to do data design with database. But how to do data design without database? example i want to do data design for embedded system without using database

Comment: "data design" can mean different things to different people. You need to describe what you mean by this term (and if you can come up with a precise description, I guess you can answer this question by yourself). FWIW, you can do "data modeling" with pencil and paper, no need for a computer at all. But I guess since this is way too obvious this is not what you have in mind.

Comment: Data design what i mean "data design (sometimes referred to
as data architecting) creates a model of data and/or information that is represented at a high level of abstraction (the customer/user’s view of data)." I refer on pressman book

Comment: I know for modeling database is use ERD with conceptual mode, physical model, or logical model but how about if i don't use database, i only use data is saved temporary in memory. What should data i should design? Array structuer? or linked list?

Comment: Tell us about the **actual real world** problem you want to solve - no fictous problem, please - where you are unsure if an array or a linked list or something else might be suited for, then we may be able to help you. Or keep those details secret and expect the question to be downvoted and closed. Your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing data design.

Data design very broadly means "thinking about how to store the data". You have already decided to not use a database. Making that decision *is* part of data design.

Aside: this is not part of your question, but there are some very lightweight databases. Are you sure that whatever you implement yourself *really* uses fewer resources than a lightweight database that has been optimized over decades by dozens of contributors to use as few resources as possible?

Comment: I still not satisfied, When i want to do data design for embedded system without database what data should i design ? LinkedList Array? Or should i skip data design phase?

Comment: Figuring out whether to use a linked list or an array *is* data design. We can't tell you which to use, since we don't know your requirements, constraints, access patterns, etc.

Comment: I just want to know, can i use a linked list or an array in data design? If i can that's answer my a question

Comment: We can't tell you whether you can use a linked list or an array, since that depends on your requirements, your constraints, your access patterns, etc.